# Exactly 30 characters random string creation in php

Tags: php, random

I am trying to create a random string which should contain 30 characters exactly. But sometimes it is creating 28 characters also. How to solve the issue?
My code is like:

```
function random_string(){
    $character_set_array = array( );
    $character_set_array[ ] = array( 'count' => 15, 'characters' => 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQURSTUVWXYZ' );
    $character_set_array[ ] = array( 'count' => 6, 'characters' => '0123456789' );
    $character_set_array[ ] = array( 'count' => 9, 'characters' => '!@#$%^&+_|~-=\{}[]:?/' );
    $temp_array = array( );
    foreach ( $character_set_array as $character_set )
    {
      for ( $i = 0; $i < $character_set[ 'count' ]; $i++ )
      {
        $temp_array[ ] = $character_set[ 'characters' ][ rand( 0, strlen( $character_set[ 'characters' ] ) - 1 ) ];
      }
    }
    shuffle( $temp_array );
    return implode( '', $temp_array );
}
```

please help me.

Comment: How are you using this string and testing its length ? Is suspect the problem is in later use (for example introduction in BD due to special chars).

Comment: I copy the whole generated string and by making use of strlen() I am getting the length of the code

Comment: Yeah! when I exclude the special characters, then it is coming properly. So is there any another process to include special characters? If so please help.

Comment: is it for only "\"? If so then I can avoid that.

Comment: I think so. Even if you end being successful in integrating it, I wouldn't dare use random "\" in my strings in a language like php with no good reason (but I'm not familiar with php internals).

Answer (score 1):

I executed the function 10.000 times and never got a string with less then 30 characters.

Comment: but I am using the same code for my module also.But getting this type of issue.

Answer (score 1):

I could not help rewriting the function. I would not be able to sleep otherwise...

```
<?php

function random_string(){

        $charset = array();

        $charset[]='abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQURSTUVWXYZ';
        $charset[]='0123456789';
        $charset[]='!@#$%^&+_|~-=\{}[]:?/';

        $res='';

        for($i=0;$i<30;$i++){
                $j=$charset[array_rand($charset)];
                $res.=$j[mt_rand(0,strlen($j)-1)];
        }

        return($res);
}

// Let us do a long test that the returned random string is always 30 characters long
for($a=0;$a<1000000;$a++){
        $z=random_string();
        if(strlen($z)!=30){print("ERR!!! --> $z");exit;}
}

// If we make it here then all is good... probably.
print("OK!\n");

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$temp_array = array( );
$temp_array[] = '\';
$temp_array[] = 'A';
echo implode( '', $temp_array );
echo '<br>length:'.strlen( implode( '', $temp_array ));
```

This displays

```
A
length:1
```

Try to remove the `\` from your list.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function random_string(){
    $character_set_array = array( );
    $character_set_array[ ] = array( 'count' => 15, 'characters' => 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQURSTUVWXYZ' );
    $character_set_array[ ] = array( 'count' => 6, 'characters' => '0123456789' );
    $character_set_array[ ] = array( 'count' => 9, 'characters' => '!@#$%^&+_|~-=\{}[]:?/' );
    $temp_array = array( );

    foreach ( $character_set_array as $character_set )
    {
      for ( $i = 0; $i < $character_set[ 'count' ]; $i++ )
      {
        $temp_array[ ] = substr($character_set[ 'characters' ], 0, rand(0, count( $character_set[ 'characters' ] ) - 1 ));
      }
    }

    shuffle( $temp_array );
    return implode( '', $temp_array );
}
```